# Remove extra space from column values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a column in Oracle database, where I had stored concatenated values. For example,

```
/uk/letters/default?/uk/letters/funny_letters? 
/uk/letters/letters?/library/conditionalstyle?o=3&f=11/uk/letters/funny_letters?    
/uk/workinglife/viewarticle_93?/library/conditionalstyle?/uk/financialcentre/car_tax_calculator?
/uk/job-hunting/default?/partners/msn/i-resignfinctr?/uk/letters/letters?/
```

In between the urls, there are some spaces in between. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = REPLACE(YourColumn, ' ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too late but will help some one.

```
select regexp_replace(column_name, '[[:space:]]+', chr(32))  from table_name;
```

After verification , you can update the table as follows;

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = REGEXP_REPLACE (column_name ,'[[:space:]]+',' ');
```